# Differentiability of bijection that pushes measures with densities to measures with densities

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, density-function, change-of-variable, pushforward

Suppose we have a Borel function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that is bijective such that its inverse is also Borel. Assume that every finite measure $\mu$ on $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$ with density $h_\mu$ with respect to Lebesgue measure satisfies that its push-forward $f_\sharp\mu:=\mu\circ f^{-1}$ also admits a density $h_{f_\sharp\mu}$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

**Question**: can we say something about the differentiability of $f$? My intuition is that $f$ should be a.e. differentiable -- sort of a converse of the change of variable formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We unfortunately cannot say that $f$ will be continuous even at a single point, let alone differentiable.

First note that your condition is equivalent to the condition that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ satisfy Luzin's condition $N$ for Borel sets, i.e., they send Borel sets of Lebesgue measure $0$ to Borel sets of Lebesgue measure $0$.  Indeed, certainly such maps satisfying condition $N$ will push absolutely continuous measures forward to absolutely continuous measures (otherwise they would map some set of positive Lebesgue measure onto a Lebesgue nullset).

Conversely, say you are given a map $f$ that preserves the condition of absolute continuity with respect to Lebesgue measure under pushforwards.  Let $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ have finite and positive Lebesgue measure.   Then $f_{\#}m\llcorner_{S}$ will have positive measure and be concentrated on $f(S)$, so absolute continuity of $f_{\#}m\llcorner_S$ implies $f(S)$ has positive Lebesgue measure as well.

However, we can construct an everywhere discontinuous bijection $f$ with condition $N$ for $f$ and $f^{-1}$ as follows.

We will instead of $\mathbb R$ use $(0,1)$.  Let $S\subseteq (0,1)$ be a Borel set such that $m(S\cap I)>0$ and $m(I\backslash S)>0$ on every interval $I\subseteq (0,1)$.  ([See here for an explicit construction of such a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4762070/1210477)). Note that we may construct $S$ in such a way that $ x\in S$ if and only if $1-x\in S$ (the linked construction satisfies this if done symmetrically).

Then define
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x & x\in S\\
1-x & x\in (0,1)\backslash S.
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f=f^{-1}$ is certainly a Borel bijection.  Moreover, $f$ satisfies condition $N$, which can be seen by restricting $f$ to $S$ and $(0,1)\backslash S$ separately.

However, $f$ is not continuous at any point except $x=\frac{1}{2}$, which can be remedied by manually switching the value of $f$ at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ with any the value of $f$ at any other point.  (Said switching will never accidentally make $f$ continuous elsewhere, since none of the discontinuities are removable.)

##### Remark

Of course, we could have simply taken $S=\mathbb Q\cap (0,1)$ and accomplished the same task, i.e., we only technically needed density of $S$ and $(0,1)\backslash S$, but the preceding example shows that we can construct our bijection so that it cannot be altered on a set of measure $0$ to be continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helpful. I wasn't familiar with Luzin's N property. An n-dimensional generalization of the [Banach-Zareckiǐ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Properties) seems to be what I'm after. Are you aware of any such result?

Comment: @mbiron I'm not unfortunately, though I wouldn't take that to mean there isn't anything out there somewhere, under the right additional conditions - haven't thought about it much so not sure what the right analogous statement would be.